# symbolicatecrash - space in bundle name preventing method names to be show in the crash report

Tags: iphone, symbolicatecrash

I'm trying to debug a crash but when I run symbolicatecrash against my crash log I get every method call in the stack trace except for my method calls.  Here is the crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: C3A58923-5D49-4767-A3C2-3AFFEF00DFEF
CrashReporter Key:   165f7337feeb98394ab7477fc0b7280d14a16e43
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Process:         Log Jam [2862]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/625E17A7-F0FF-4109-9E62-99FE8D6C6889/Log Jam.app/Log Jam
Identifier:      Log Jam
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-12-13 23:31:20.762 -0500
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7c2d4 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7c2c4 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7c2b6 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d90d72 abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x34981a20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34a83594 _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3497fdf2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3497fe46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3497ff16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34a824c4 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3587a7c2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 62
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3587a7fc +[NSException raise:format:] + 28
12  QuartzCore                      0x31071222 CALayerSetPosition(CALayer*, CA::Vec2<double> const&, bool) + 134
13  QuartzCore                      0x31071190 -[CALayer setPosition:] + 32
14  QuartzCore                      0x310710dc -[CALayer setFrame:] + 384
15  UIKit                           0x341aa0e2 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 182
16  UIKit                           0x341aad64 -[UILabel setFrame:] + 204
17  Log Jam                 0x00052dec 0x1000 + 335340
18  Log Jam                 0x0004934c 0x1000 + 295756
19  Log Jam                 0x00048ffa 0x1000 + 294906
20  UIKit                           0x341ef630 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 604
21  UIKit                           0x341ef358 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 176
22  UIKit                           0x341e30be -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 634
23  UIKit                           0x341e2e34 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 28
24  Log Jam                 0x0002f792 0x1000 + 190354
25  UIKit                           0x3420b834 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 656
26  UIKit                           0x342cb60c -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 124
27  Foundation                      0x31181df6 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 362
28  CoreFoundation                  0x3583109c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 8
29  CoreFoundation                  0x35830b54 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 844
30  CoreFoundation                  0x358021ae __CFRunLoopRun + 1082
31  CoreFoundation                  0x35801c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
32  CoreFoundation                  0x35801b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
33  GraphicsServices                0x320c84a4 GSEventRunModal + 108
34  GraphicsServices                0x320c8550 GSEventRun + 56
35  UIKit                           0x341dc322 -[UIApplication _run] + 406
36  UIKit                           0x341d9e8c UIApplicationMain + 664
37  Log Jam                 0x00002172 0x1000 + 4466
38  Log Jam                 0x0000213c 0x1000 + 4412






Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d30974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30dda704 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30dda174 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30dd9b98 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7e24a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d76970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7e9e0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7e364 _pthread_wqthread + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d76970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d04268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d06354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35802648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35801ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35801c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35801b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x34bf6124 RunWebThread(void*) + 332
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7d886 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d72a88 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d04268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d06354 mach_msg + 44
2   AudioToolbox                    0x33c0eb96 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 54
3   AudioToolbox                    0x33b4a1d2 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 138
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7d886 _pthread_start + 242
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d72a88 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d04268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d06354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35802648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35801ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35801c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35801b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x3118e5f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x3116c192 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x31165242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7d886 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d72a88 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d2868c select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x35839662 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7d886 _pthread_start + 242
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d72a88 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3e3d52e8
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3497f989      r6: 0x03b74ccc      r7: 0x2fdfe3ac
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x00236e70     r11: 0x344b5cd8
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fdfe3ac      lr: 0x30d7c2cb      pc: 0x30d7c2d4
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0xabfff +Log Jam armv7  <467edd9ddbc1a52a6bb7009036bc5360> /var/mobile/Applications/625E17A7-F0FF-4109-9E62-99FE8D6C6889/Log Jam.app/Log Jam
  0x1ed000 -   0x1eefff  dns.so armv7  <fcefecb2d5e095ba88127eec3af57ec0> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe27fff  dyld armv7  <06e6959cebb4a72e66c833e26ae64d26> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3001f000 - 0x30026fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <2989ea7a5cad2cfe91bd632b041d0ff4> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x30054000 - 0x3016afff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <e7fbb2ac586567e574dc33d7bb5c4dc9> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x301cd000 - 0x302b6fff  AudioCodecs armv7  <be315c1e4982718460819fb240042952> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioCodecs
0x302b7000 - 0x30366fff  WebKit armv7  <644a1c6120578f896bed7121307aa2af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x30367000 - 0x3037dfff  EAP8021X armv7  <36659ec2b9def7b5798a05327e369247> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x303fc000 - 0x3051cfff  CoreGraphics armv7  <2d7b40a7baca915ce78b1dd9a0d6433b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x3056b000 - 0x3056bfff  vecLib armv7  <e53d234e808c77d286161095f92c58cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30641000 - 0x30700fff  CFNetwork armv7  <02fe0e30e54fffdcbbbd02e8cb812c3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3075b000 - 0x3076efff  libmis.dylib armv7  <855aefc263c6c20e6cf8723ea36125a2> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x3076f000 - 0x307c4fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <9365fc6cae1bff737257e74faf3b1f26> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x307d8000 - 0x307defff  StoreKit armv7  <f44ec361fe53962128632c6f3afd869b> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
0x307e6000 - 0x307e8fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <e66758bcda6da5d7f9b54fa5c4de6da2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x30811000 - 0x30813fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <30a5f1edcdb9ffe868a620199a4cbe12> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x30821000 - 0x30853fff  AppSupport armv7  <47c8055ac99f187174ca373b702ffa68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x30854000 - 0x30854fff  Accelerate armv7  <29dd5f17440bbb6e8e42e11b6fceda9a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3091c000 - 0x30931fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <ea156820997ae9a2baf664d0f79f18d7> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x30b44000 - 0x30b46fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <1040629f37795146c9dcac8ab1a868fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x30c45000 - 0x30c74fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <3f982c11b5526fc39a92d585c60d8a90> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x30c78000 - 0x30c8dfff  OpenAL armv7  <8ea22c729b71c6e7e19566b91a03afd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/OpenAL
0x30c8e000 - 0x30c98fff  AccountSettings armv7  <19c79f81d5d55fe2e6b618fcdc28258e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x30d03000 - 0x30e14fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <138a43ab528bb428651e6aa7a2a7293c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x30e16000 - 0x30e28fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <cd2a699aa5036bdad0517603ba4db839> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x30e37000 - 0x30f1ffff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <1f478a71783cd7eb4ae9ef6f2dcea803> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x30f20000 - 0x30f2bfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <fabaddbcbc8c02bab0261df9d78e0e25> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x30fc4000 - 0x31065fff  Celestial armv7  <b411f4662383ec24dbfbcde8f4c23d67> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x31066000 - 0x31114fff  QuartzCore armv7  <83a8e5f0033369e437069c1e758fed83> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x31161000 - 0x31280fff  Foundation armv7  <81d36041f04318cb51db5aafed9ce504> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x312af000 - 0x312b4fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <5f73c7138ee1cb7103a98aec99f9ed88> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x312c3000 - 0x31306fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <27ac7f05482a8aa9977150f34f9be6eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x31307000 - 0x31347fff  CoreAudio armv7  <f32e03ee4c68f0db23f05afc9a3cc94c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31429000 - 0x3142cfff  ApplePushService armv7  <9d1eb7b11f0f146c941efbab2c055606> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x318b5000 - 0x318d5fff  PrintKit armv7  <02a9c6f4173a0673c4637a3b570345cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x31bd9000 - 0x31c02fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <54484a513761868149405df7fc29b5c0> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x31c5e000 - 0x31c66fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <6d6c62f52219d27be50f1d7c39a68dc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x31c68000 - 0x31c6bfff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <a2af7147f5538d7669b14fa7b19b5a7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x31c6d000 - 0x31d16fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <b3d82f80a777cb1434052ea2d232e3df> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x31d29000 - 0x31d2cfff  IOSurface armv7  <deff02882166bf16d0765d68f0542cc8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x31d2d000 - 0x31d2ffff  MobileInstallation armv7  <8e6b0d9f642be06729ffdaaee97053b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x31d46000 - 0x31d4dfff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <71372c95d4af7af787d0682a939e40ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x31e09000 - 0x31e4bfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <96d3af505b9f2887e62c7e99c157733e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x320c4000 - 0x320d0fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <0099670dccd99466653956bf918d667a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33ae9000 - 0x33aebfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <3f0b58ea13d30f0cdb73f6ffe6d4e75c> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x33b49000 - 0x33c82fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <657b327f2ceee9f22f9474f2f9bddbe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x33cf8000 - 0x33d29fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <bb7ff9014b1dabec2acce95d41f05b59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x33d2c000 - 0x33d2ffff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <3a385ed495379116abbe50bc8cd5a612> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33d30000 - 0x33d31fff  CoreSurface armv7  <f7caaf43609cfe0e475dfe83790edb4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x33d61000 - 0x33d7afff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ee16b5cee12a8947c8e511ed51ae7fef> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x340dc000 - 0x34112fff  CoreText armv7  <b9b5c21b2d2a28abc47842c78c026ddf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3415c000 - 0x3418ffff  AddressBook armv7  <7c87e0175c8649d6832419da8a1cfac1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x341a5000 - 0x34526fff  UIKit armv7  <de1cbd3219a74e4d41b30428f428e223> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x34527000 - 0x345bafff  ImageIO armv7  <5b5a294d4250eff866fdbf891b1e8b34> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x345ca000 - 0x34607fff  CoreMedia armv7  <4ea4d349e886206d1ecf5bae870f3f04> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x34632000 - 0x34636fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e861a330d14702f148ca5133dcbe954c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34637000 - 0x34774fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <a18bbcc41a38917fe0ae5e183d3f6b07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x34775000 - 0x34822fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <3f2df600942dc72aad312b3cc98ec479> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x34852000 - 0x3485bfff  CoreVideo armv7  <2092d5deb6b234e04678b7c1878ccd81> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3492e000 - 0x3493afff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <137b75e19b2450c234dec88d538798ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3493d000 - 0x34987fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <53a6e7239c3908fa8c2915b65ff3b056> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x34a7d000 - 0x34b3efff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <aaf5671a35f9ac20d5846703dafaf4c6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34b3f000 - 0x35127fff  WebCore armv7  <d6bd9cf88ee82ab6b0e33e0ae1190772> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x3520f000 - 0x352fcfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <c72b45f471df092dbd849081f7a3ef53> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x353e7000 - 0x353ecfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <cec3f3271fc267c32c169ed03e312d63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3549d000 - 0x354d5fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <374bd566263e8929c10d50d6a6a48a46> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x35553000 - 0x35560fff  OpenGLES armv7  <a12565ffb5bb42e3019f1957cd4951d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x355b6000 - 0x355bcfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <5bbd9b3f5cfece328f80c403a8805ce9> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x357da000 - 0x358c0fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <01441e01f5141a50ee723362e59ca400> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x35992000 - 0x3599ffff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0f4e595e6eb2170aceb729f32b5de8c2> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x35b60000 - 0x35babfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <251c5ac7380802a16e30d827c027c637> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x35bac000 - 0x35e46fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <2e77d87e96af938aacf0a6008e6fb89d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x35fca000 - 0x35fd2fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b29d4c5e300ef81060e38f72bb583c02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x3601b000 - 0x3603afff  Bom armv7  <0f5fd6057bad5e1677869500d636821f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3603b000 - 0x3603cfff  DataMigration armv7  <babbc72d4d48325de147d5103d7bc00d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3603d000 - 0x360acfff  ProofReader armv7  <d2e62a8ab7e1460c7f6de8913c703e6d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x360ad000 - 0x36129fff  AVFoundation armv7  <4c7356c795e01bd5c21b00a409a07476> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x3612f000 - 0x36137fff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <854e82fe66feef01e54c7c8a209851ac> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x36138000 - 0x3616ffff  Security armv7  <cd28e102950634ae7167ddee9c686d36> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x36170000 - 0x361bdfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <55038e5c1d4d0dbdd94295e8cad7a9a4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x361be000 - 0x361f8fff  IOKit armv7  <eb932cc42d60e55d9a4d0691bcc3d9ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3623f000 - 0x3627efff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <a7c117c92607a512823d307b8fdd0151> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
```

As you can see, its not very helpful :-(  Any help symbolicating this report would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer for hints on how to check if symbolication can work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13660458/474794

Or this answer on how to symbolicate manually: [iOS crash reports: atos not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected/13576028#13576028)

Addition to the general problem:

If the application has special characters like spaces or apostrophe's in it, the default Apple toolchain will not be able to symbolicate it. The reason is that the tool `otool`, which being used in the toolchain, can't handle that. No matter how you pass the filename. So to fix this, you have to do the following:

1. Rename the dSYM package and remove all special chars, e.g. from `My App's.app.dSYM` to `MyApps.app.dSYM`
2. Open the content inside the package and navigate down to `Contents/Resources/DWARF`
3. Rename the file in there as you did above

Now try again. Best way to avoid all this: NEVER use special chars in your apps name. If you want the adjust the name that appears on the screen, use CFBundleDisplayName or the corresponding plist entries.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out the problem with symbolicatecrash, but I was able to get the missing method calls by following this tutorial.

http://www.picsoftware.ca/blog/?p=8

Worked like a charm!